# I Want to make a startup window in python Tkinter which should not have minimize, maximize and close button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How can I do that?
I want to make a window without close, maximize and minimize button, it will be my toplevel window.

Comment: Thank u. I made using overredirect(1) method.

Comment: I want to hide only minimize button of Toplevel of my root window in tkinter. Is  there any way?